# Accessing element of the json file with multiple objects

Tags: javascript, html, json, node.js

how do i access the property of different object in the same json file? in node.js/javascript.
JSON FILE

```
{
    "fname1": "aa",
    "lname1": "aa",
    "DOB1": "aa",
    "gender1": "m",
    "E-mail#1.1": "aa",
    "Acode1": "+1",
    "Bcode1": "",
    "cell": "000-000-0000",
    "Ccode1": "+1",
    "Dcode3": "",
    "homeCell": "",
    "Address_l1.1": "aa",
    "Address_l1.2": "aa",
    "city1": "aa",
    "Province1": "aa",
    "country1": "Canada"
}{
    "fname1": "a",
    "lname1": "aa",
    "DOB1": "aa",
    "gender1": "m",
    "E-mail#1.1": "aa",
    "Acode1": "+1",
    "Bcode1": "",
    "cell": "000-000-0000",
    "Ccode1": "+1",
    "Dcode3": "",
    "homeCell": "",
    "Address_l1.1": "aa",
    "Address_l1.2": "aa",
    "city1": "aa",
    "Province1": "aa",
    "country1": "Canada"
}
```

server command

```
if(req.method === 'GET' && req.url === '/users.html'){

var filepath = './Data/users.json';
fs.readFile(filepath, "UTF-8",function(err,contents){
    if(err){
        console.log('error during reading json file');
        throw err;
    }
    else{

        console.log('nikal bc');
        //var data = JSON.parse(contents);
        // console.log(data[1].fname);
        console.log(contents);
        console.log(contents[1].fname1);
        var table = '';
        var no_users = array.length;
        var cols = 16;

        for(var r = 1; r < no_users; r++){
            table += '<tr>';
        }


        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
        res.write(contents);
        res.end();
    }
});
```

i tried this method of contents[1].fname1 but it doesnt work.please help. it gives me undefiend however on console.log(contents); that gives me the whole json file on my console.

Comment: Your `myObj` assignment is invalid and produces _"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {"_. Did you mean to use an array? `myObj = [{...}, {...}]`

Comment: Make myObj as array `myObj = [{}, {}]`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the brackets  to make it an array..

```
var my_array = [{ "name":"John", "age":30, "car":null },{ "name":"John", "age":30, "car":null }];
```

Then it will work exactly as you tried. As it currently is, you have a single object assigned to the variable, and then a free-floating object that's  not doing anything.

Also, it's just a Javascript object/array. It's not JSON.

Comment: @AryanArora - What JSON file. Your question has nothing to do with a JSON file. I'm not clairvoyant so you're gonna have to be more specific.

Comment: i am doing an assignment that made a json file out of the form submitted by the user. i just used this as an example.

Comment: so it creates a json file like {fname: , lname:}{fname: lname:} but i cant access them since when i write console.log(contents[1].fname) it gives me undefined. contents from (fs.readFile(filepath, "UTF-8",function(err,contents){.......)

Comment: i don't know what you're talking about. that's not valid json. you need to post a complete example of exactly what you're doing.

Comment: m sorry, i just edited it .. please have a look. i have been stuck for hours now

Comment: @AryanArora - That is **not valid json**. I hope, after repeating that four times you understand the problem. Your JSON is wrong. You've got an answer and 2 comments explaining exactly what is wrong with your JSON. I don't know what else to tell you. Good luck.